# How to read specific column one by one till the defined column number?

Tags: apache-poi, katalon-studio

I have existing codes that work to get a particular cell from an excel sheet.

I have input data in excel sheet from cell C2 till cell T2.

Current codes allowed me to read cell C2 once.

I wanted to make it automatically read C2, D2, E2, ..... till T2

Codes:

```html
public String ReadCellData(int vRow, int vColumn)
 {
  String value=null;          //variable for storing the cell value
  Workbook wb=null;           //initialize Workbook null
  try
  {
   //reading data from a file in the form of bytes
      FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + "/Data Files/testmatrix.xlsx");
   //constructs an XSSFWorkbook object, by buffering the whole stream into the memory
   wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch(IOException e1)
  {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
  Sheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);   //getting the XSSFSheet object at given index
  Row row=sheet.getRow(vRow); //returns the logical row
  Cell cell=row.getCell(vColumn); //getting the cell representing the given column
  //value=cell.getStringCellValue();    //getting cell value
  //return value;               //returns the cell value
 }
}
```

**codes to get and print data**

```html
//read excel cell C2, ignore first row column A1. (int vRow, int vColumn)
def exceldata = CustomKeywords.'test.readexcel.ReadCellData'(2, 2)

String jsondata = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(exceldata.toString())

println(jsondata)

WebUI.delay(1)

//call the object and post the above data as API HTTP request body
def post = ((findTestObject('Object Repository/Web Service Request/test-service/Post')) as RequestObject)

post.setBodyContent(new HttpTextBodyContent(jsondata))

WebUI.delay(2)

//POST and verification
def response = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(post)

println(response.statusCode)

assert response.getStatusCode() == 201
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the For loop and iterate the loop and get the value

Example

```
def exceldata="";
for(int row =1;row<=2;row++)
{
for(int col=1;col<=5;col++)
{
exceldata = CustomKeywords.'test.readexcel.ReadCellData'(row,col) 
}
}
```